# Loop through current widget instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently in the process of writing my own hinter widget using UI widget factory. For my turnOn and turnOff methods, I want either all my hints to be turned on or off OR if i pass an array of hint id's to this methods, they will turn on or off specifically only those with the ids.

Widget looks like this at the moment:

```
$.widget("ui.hint", {
   options: {
      id: '1',
      text: 'This is a hint',
      position: 'top',
      offset: '0%',
      hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
},
 _create: function() {
    var o = this.options, 
        el = this.element,
        shell =  $('<div></div>').addClass('ui-hint ui-hint-     '+o.position).text(o.text).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        minHeight: 100,
        minWidth: 100,
        background: 'rgb(250, 255, 189)',
        zIndex: 9999
        });


    el.addClass('ui-hint-target');

    this._trigger('beforeShow', null, shell) //added event before placing into dom

    shell.insertAfter(el); 

    switch (o.position) {
        case 'top':
            shell.position({
                "my": "center bottom",
                "at": "center top",
                "of": el,
                "offset": o.offset+" -25%",
                "collision": 'none none'
            });
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            shell.position({
                "my": "center top",
                "at": "center bottom",
                "of": el,
                "offset": o.offset+" 25%",
                "collision": 'none none'
            });
            break;
        case 'left':
            shell.position({
                "my": "right center",
                "at": "left center",
                "of": el,
                "offset": "-25% "+o.offset,
                "collision": 'none none'
            });
            break;
        case 'right':
            shell.position({
                "my": "left center",
                "at": "right center",
                "of": el,
                "offset": "25% "+o.offset,
                "collision": 'none none'
            });
            break;      
    }



},
_setOption: function(key, value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.options[key] = value;
      this._render();
     return this;
}
    else {
    return this.options[key];
   }
},
hide: function() {    
    this.element.next().hide("fast"); 
    this._trigger('afterHide', null, this.element.next()); 
}, 
show: function() {
    this._trigger('beforeShow', null, this.element.next());
    this.element.next().show("fast"); 
},
    hint: function() {
  return this.element.next();
}

});
```

My question is, how can i organize those methods? I imagine I should loop through each instance of the widget and compare the values with their id's yet i don't know how. Will appreciate any advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be understanding your question fully, but if I was you I'd use a class rather than Id's to select multiple elements.  Then you can use jquery's each method you can do something like:

```
$('.ui-hint').each(function(i, el) {
    var $myHint = $(el);
    console.log('index: ', i, ' jquery el: ', $myHint);
});
```

Comment: I'd use that but I DO need ids because they will be later used on the server for statistics, etc. I might have confused you a bit, but Ids aren't html hooks, they are just one of the options for the widget instance.

Comment: You can still use Id's but for the purposes of selecting multiple, use their class and the each method, as described.